# Como cambiar tamaño de imagen un ImageButton de forma dinamica

Tags: android, scale

Estoy creando un juego en el cual necesito que unas ImageButton(representan a mis jugadores, y forman un tablero) varien su tamaño dependendiendo de una variable entera que tiene la clase jugador, quisiera saber como darle distintos tamaños pasandoles un numero de alto y ancho o de escala[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora lo resolví escalando BitMaps

```
//cargo mi imagen en desde resources a un bitmap
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ballgreen_small);
// manipulo el tamaño de la imagen con coordenadas x e y (ballSize)
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, ballSize, ballSize, false);
tiles[i]
//le cargo el la nueva imagen redimensionada a mi imageview
[j].getImageView().setImageBitmap(scaled);
tiles[i][j].getImageView().setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

¿Hay alguna mejor opción?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarte mejor y publicar tu código?

Comment: Bitmaps para redimensionar??? Desconozco a que te refieres podrias explicar mas a detalle como resolviste agregando código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que tu solucion fue creando un bitmap escalado de la versión original. Creo que la mejor opción es usar imagenes **[Draw 9 patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)** dentro de los `ImageView` y esta opción no requiere de procesamiento, simplemente tienes que crear las guias en tu grafico para que la imagen se adecue correctamente al area del `ImageView`.

[image]

Te recomiendo este tutorial en español me parece excelente.
http://www.jtech.ua.es/cursos/apuntes/moviles/daa2013/sesion03-apuntes.html